# How to handle events from Server in each Client thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns

I have one `Server` modifying `Data : IData` and many `Client` instances interested in `IData`'s events.

I want `Server` to run on a separate thread, and to have no delay while modifying `Data`

I want each `Client` run a separate thread with equal priorities between each other.

And I want each `Client` to preserve the right order of `IData` calls.

How to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a [pub/sub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) pattern.

You can use [MemBus](https://github.com/flq/MemBus) for in-process message bus. It can be easily configured and supports both synchronous and asynchronous processing.

Your `Server` will be pushing `IData` events to the bus and multiple `Clients` that subscribe to the same bus will receive the messages in the same order as the server sent them. Each `Client` instance can be called on a separate thread.